# Getting data from listboxitem on tap

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I have a user control which I use as a listboxItem. On this user control there is an image and  if that image is tapped I want to access the data of the item itself.

For example:
I load all contacts into the listbox and on tap of the image I want to initialize a phonecall task. Let's say the phone number and name of the contact are in two different texblocks inside the user control. How can I get these two values into my task?

I tried finding the values in the sender object but couldn't do it.

It's a pretty basic question but I can't seem to find the answer, could someone help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try something like `var selected = ((ListBox) sender).SelectedItem as MyCustomControl;` in your listbox selection changed event?

That should give you access to your custom control object where you can access the phone number and name properties.

* actual syntax may vary *

Comment: As far as having access to the properties everything works perfectly, thanks for that. Do you happen to know how I would have to alter this code in order to work in the tap-event of an image inside the control and not the control itself? I'm trying to figure it out myself but I figured asking you if you had any idea couldn't hurt.

Comment: I'd have to play around a bit, but since your image is part of your user control you would probably need to either raise an event on your control that the image was tapped (so you could handle that by any page using the control for flexibility) or handle the tap directly in your user control.